# Bash assistance recursively grepping directory using a file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a txt file (which often gets updated) called *hitlist.txt* containing a list of words/strings I want to `grep` a directory against ... like:

```
# This is just a comment and will not be part of the search
* Blah - this is a category  
foo
bar
sibilance

# A new category
* Meh - another category
snakefish
sex panther
```

My list is typically *> 100* strings, and each is on its own line. Today, because of a deadline, I simply went through the list and executed the following command for each word:

```
    find -iname "*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -HniI "foo" >> results.txt
```

As indicated in the command above, I am interested in the file path and name, as well as the line the contains the matched text. There are multiple categories list in the file (denoted by `*`) and I would like to be able to run my script against one, more, or all categories.

I would also like to be able to turn off the `-i` flag (case sensitivity) as an option. I have a script that recursively finds/lists all files in a directory, and the command I have been using above. Lastly the *hitlist* format can be changed completely if necessary.

Comment: There are multiple, distinct questions here. One is how to extract a single category in a wordlist from a file. A separate question is how to grep for any question in a given list (that one's very, very easy -- a quick perusal of the man page or POSIX specification for `grep` will trivially answer it). Try solving them individually, and asking individual questions about parts you have trouble with -- transforming specs to code for free isn't what we do here (that's, generally speaking, what we get paid for).

Comment: That technically does count as a suggestion.

Comment: Sure, but "suggestions" aren't what StackOverflow does, which is why I'm *commenting*, not answering, right now. We're a Q&A database: We collect questions and their answers. If something is asked to solicit discussion rather than to solicit a canonical answer, it's explicitly outside the site rules. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask are worth reading.

Comment: No worries, that just gave me a grin. I began my professional life as a software engineer, did what everyone else here probably has done/did. Since then I have moved off into a different field within the space community and only then did I notice the difference in forum policy/philosophy.  I love stack overflow, and many other communities I have used in the past, and I get what you are saying, but the coding community is much more inclined to shotgun an RTFM, or a negative response than to discuss the problem with the requester, which is weird.  Regardless, thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: *nod*. There is, indeed, much more focus on collecting quality, reusable questions than on making the process easy for folks asking those questions; the argument has been made -- and supported by the how site culture has changed with popularity/volume -- that this is essential to keep quality up while scaling. Anyhow -- if you do at some point ask a question narrowed to be in-scope (such as how to extract words associated with specified category sets, or how to search for all words named in such a result without storing it in a temporary file), feel free to @-notify me; I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Is there a `grep` missing in your example? The `-iname '*'` seems superfluous; if you want to find all files, just don't put a file name constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a `ghl()` (***g***rep **h**it**l**ist) shell function to do the work, (depends on *GNU* `grep`'s `-o` switch, plus a little `sed` loop), the output is a list of words from *hitlist.txt* (or `<filename>`):

```
# usage ghl <glob> <filename>
ghl() { grep -o '\* '"$1"' -' "$2" | grep -o '[[:alpha:]]*' | \
         while read x ; do \
             sed -n '/\* '"$1"'/{:show ;n;/^[^ ]/{p;b show;}}' "$2" ; \
         done ; }
```

Pipe the word list output of `ghl` with an "`.*ah`" wildcard, (which matches the *Blah* category), into `grep -f -`, plus some *ad hoc* `bash` [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to generate input text:

```
ghl '.*ah' hitlist.txt | grep -i -f - <(echo bar) <(echo foo) <(echo Foo)
```

Output:

```
/dev/fd/63:bar
/dev/fd/62:foo
/dev/fd/61:Foo
```

The 2nd `grep` above can be passed switches as desired, (see `man grep`).  Example, the same thing, but case sensitive, (i.e. remove the `-i` switch):

```
ghl '.*ah' hitlist.txt | grep -f - <(echo bar) <(echo foo) <(echo Foo)
```

Output, (note missing uppercase item):

```
/dev/fd/63:bar
/dev/fd/62:foo
```

Since `grep` already has options to handle recursive searches, the rest is only a matter of adding switches as required.

Comment: The `-o` option is not a GNU `grep` extension. This looks vaguely like it wants to be an Awk script.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry, it's unclear as to whether `is not a GNU ... extension`  refers to the 1) existence, 2) origin, or 3) <some other attribute>, of the `-o` switch.  Please clarify...

Comment: It's not in POSIX but it is fairly widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely vague, but I'm imagining this is more or less what you are looking for.

```
awk -v cat='Blah|Meh' 'NR==FNR && /^#/ { next } # Skip comments
    NR==FNR && /^\*/ { if ($0~cat) c=1; else c=0; next }
    NR==FNR { if(c) a[$0]=1; next }
    lower($0) in a { print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0 }' Hits.txt files to search
```

Figuring out how to selectively disable `lower()` and rigging it to read a list of file names other than `Hits.txt` from `find` should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Rough-cut question, rough-cut answer. Thereeare probably typos etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

hitlist format:

```
# MEH
never,going,to give,you up

# blah
word to,your,mother
```

Script:

```
# Set defaults
OUTPUT_FILE="hits.txt"
HITLIST_FILE="hitlist.txt"

# Hold on to the args
ARGLIST=($*)

# Declare any functiions
help ()
{
    echo "--------------------------------- Luffa --------------------------------" 
        echo "Usage: luffa.sh [DIRTOSCRUB]"
        echo ""
        echo "Searches DIRTOSCRUB for category specific words in $HITLIST_FILE."
        echo ""
    echo "EXAMPLE: luffa.sh dirtoscrub"
    echo ""
    echo "--help                     display this help and exit"
    echo "--version                  display version information and exit"
}

version ()
{
    echo "luffa.sh v1.0" 
}

process () 
{
    if [ ${#FILEARG} -lt 1 ] # check for proper number of args
    then
        echo "ERROR: Specify directory to be searched."
        help
        exit 1
    else
            SEARCH_DIR=${ARGLIST[0]}
        fi

    echo ""
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------- Luffa ---------------------------------------------------" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
        echo "search command: find [DIRTOSCRUB] -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI --color=always $word | tee -a ../hits.txt | more" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
        echo
        echo "                                                     .,,:::::." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                   
        echo "                                                  .,,::::~:::::.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"               
        echo "                                                ,,::::~~~~~~::~~:::." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"            
        echo "                                              ,:,:~:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~::." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"           
        echo "                                            ,,:::~:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~," | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"          
        echo "                                        .,,::::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~::" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"         
        echo "                                      .,::~:~~~~~=~~~~=~~~~~~~~~~~=~~~~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"        
        echo "                                    ,::::~~:~~~=~~~~~~~~=~~=~~~===~~~~~~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"       
        echo "                                ..:::~~~~=~~=~~~~~~=~~~~=~~===~~==~~~~~~," | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"       
        echo "                              .,:::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=~=~~~=~====~===~~~~~~~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"     
        echo "                            .,::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=~=~~~~~=~======~=~~~~=~=~~~:" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"    
        echo "                         ..,::~:~~~~~~=~~~=~~~~~~~~=~====+======~===~~~~~~~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"    
        echo "                       ..,:,:~~~~~~=~::~~=~=~~~=~~=~=~=~======~~~==~~~~~~::." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"    
        echo "                        ,,.::~:=~~~~~~~~~~~~=~=~===~~~====+==~=====~~~~~::,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"    
        echo "                        ,,,,:I++=:~==~=~~~~~~=~:==~=~+~====~=~===~~~~:~::,:" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"     
        echo "                       .,:+++?77+?=~~~~=~~=~=~~=~~+=~+~~+====~=~~~:::::,::," | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"     
        echo "                      ..++++?++?II?=~~=~~~=~~~====~===~=====~~~:~::::::::,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"     
        echo "                    ..=++?++++++???7+~~~~~~~~+~=~=====~~~~~~~~~::::~:::,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"     
        echo "                   .=+++++++++++++++===:~~=~==+~~=~=~~:~~=~:~:::~::::,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"       
        echo "                  .++++++?++++++?++=?~:~~~~===~==~==~~~~~:::::::::,,,..." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"        
        echo "               ..=?+++++??+++++++===~::~~~~~~=~~~~~~:~~:::::,:,,,,,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"            
        echo "            ...=+?+++++++++=====~:,::,~:::~~~~~:~~~~::::~::::,,,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"             
        echo "          .=+++++++++++===~==::::,::~~,,,::~~~~~~::::::~:,:,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                
        echo "        ..++++++++++=+===~,.,,:::,:~~~~~,.,:~:~::::::,::,:,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                   
        echo "    ...++?++++++++=+=~~.   ..,,,,,:,~,::~,:::,:,:,~::::,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                    
        echo "   .++++++++?++====~.       ...,,:,~::~=::,::,:,:::,,,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                        
        echo ".++?+++++?++++==~..           .,.:,,:::~,:,,,:::::,,,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                         
        echo "++++++?+???==~=.               ...,::~~~:,,:,:::,,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                           
        echo "?+++?????+==~.                   ..,,,,::,:,,,,,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                              
        echo "+?+++??+==~.                       ..,,,,,,,,." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                                 
        echo "+I???+==~.                           ..,,.." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                                     
        echo "??++==~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                                                                       
        echo "+===~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                                                                         
        echo "+=~." | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                                                                           
        echo "~" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"                             
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"

        echo "" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"

        # Loop through hitlist

        while read -re hitList || [[ -n "$hitList" ]]
        do

        # If first character is "#" it's a comment, or line is blank, skip
           if [ "$(echo $hitListWords | head -c 1)" != "#" ]; then

                if [ ! -z "$hitListWords" -a "$hitListWords" != "" ]; then

                   # Parse comma delimited category specific hitlist
                   IFS=',' read -ra categoryWords <<< "$hitListWords"

                   # Search for occurences/hits for the hitList word
                   for categoryWord in "${categoryWords[@]}"; do
                       echo "---------------------------------------------------" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
                       echo "$category - \"$categoryWord"\" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
                       echo "---------------------------------------------------" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
                       eval 'find "$SEARCH_DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI "$categoryWord" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"'
                       eval 'find "$SEARCH_DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI --color=always "$categoryWord" | more'
                       echo "" | tee -a "$OUTPUT_FILE"
                   done

               fi

           else

               category="$(echo "$hitListWords" | cut -d "#" -f 2)"

       fi

        done < "$HITLIST_FILE"

        exit $?
}

# Process the options
while [[ "${ARGLIST[0]}" == -* ]]; do
    OPTION="${ARGLIST[0]}"
    NUM_OPTS=1;

    case $OPTION in
    --version)
        version
        exit 0
        ;;
    --help)
        help
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        help
        exit 1  
        ;;
    esac

        ARGLIST=(${ARGLIST[@]:$NUM_OPTS})

done

FILEARG=${ARGLIST[@]}
process
```